# Does $f'(x) = g'(x)$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ imply $f(x) = g(x) + c$ for all $x \in [a ,b]$?

Tags: calculus

My question is regarding the open and closed intervals in the statement. I can see why the result holds on the open interval $(a, b)$, but does it also hold at the endpoints $a$ and $b$?

EDIT: Here is some more context on the question.

This appears in the proof that if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$, $f$ is integrable on $[a, b]$.

Let $L(x) = L \int_a ^ x f$ and $U(x) = U \int_a ^x f$ be the lower and upper integrals evaluated on $[a, x]$, where $x \in (a, b)$. It is shown that
\begin{equation*}
 L'(x) = U'(x) = f(x)
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in (a, b)$. The author then states without proof that this implies there exists a number $c$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 U(x) = L(x) + c
\end{equation*}
for all $x \in [a, b]$. The inclusion of the right endpoint $b$ is necessary in completing the proof.

In my question, I have substituted $L(x), U(x)$ with $f(x), g(x)$. To the best of my knowledge, all we know about $L(x)$ and $U(x)$ at this point is that they are differentiable on $(a, b)$.

Comment: No:  $(a,b) = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = \delta(x)$ and $g(x) = \delta(x-1)$.

Comment: You can apply Lagrange`s Mean Value Theorem on the continous funcion $h(x)=f-g$ on the closed interval [a,b] and see that it holds true. (If indeed f,g are continous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b))

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Is $\delta$ the Dirac distribution? That's not a function.

Comment: Glad to see someone studying this nice proof of integrability of continuous functions. This proof is from Spivak and not widely popular like the one via uniform continuity.

Comment: You should note (or prove yourself) that the functions $L, U$ are continuous on $[a, b] $ for any bounded function $f$ and your job is done by applying mean value theorem for $L-U$ on interval $[a, b]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comments into an answer.

---

Probably you are studying the proof of integrability of continuous functions from Spivak's *Calculus*. This particular proof based on derivative of upper and lower Darboux integrals is not as popular as the one via uniform continuity.

You should first prove that if $f$ is any bounded function on interval $[a, b] $ then its upper and lower Darboux integrals $L, U$ given by $$L(x) =\underline{\int_{a}^{x}} f(t) \, dt,\, U(x) =\overline{\int_{a} ^{x}} f(t) \, dt$$ are continuous on interval $[a, b] $.

Next one establishes that if $c\in[a, b] $ and $f$ is continuous at $c$ then $L'(c)= U'(c)=f(c) $. If $c$ is an end point then the above statement refers to one sided continuity and differentiability.

Thus if $f$ is continuous on $[a, b] $ then $L, U$ are continuous on $[a, b] $ and also differentiable on $[a, b] $ (one sided derivatives at end points) and $L'(x) =U'(x) =f(x), \forall x\in[a, b] $. Your job is now complete via application of mean value theorem on $L-U$ on $[a, b] $.

I have given outline of the proof and if you need more details let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed the proof I am studying. After applying MVT to $L - U$, I ended up with $(L - U)(b) = (L - U)(a)$ since $(L - U)' = 0$ everywhere. However, I can't see how to turn this into $L = U + c$ everywhere.

Comment: @tmakino: When the derivative vanishes on an interval, the function vanishes on the closure of the interval, provided the function is continuous on the closure. Since $(L-U) '=0$ it follows that $L-U=c$ on $[a, b] $.

Comment: @tmakino: consider for example the function $L-U$ on interval $[a, x] $ instead of $[a, b] $ and apply mean value theorem.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$, then, yes, it is true. For instance,$$f(a)=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)+c=g(a)+c.$$The same argument applies to $b$.

Comment: Why assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous on $[a,b]$?  That is precisely what the OP does *not* want to assume.  Instead, they are continuous just on $(a,b)$---big and central difference.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork WIthout assuming that, the statement is obviously false. Let's wait and see what the OP has to say.

Comment: Doesn't differentiability on $[a,b]$ automatically implies continuity on $[a,b]$ or am I missing something ?

Comment: @AlexKChen You are missing the endpoints. $(a,b)=[a,b]\setminus\{a,b\}$. Differentiability on $(a,b)$ implies continuity on $(a,b)$, not on $[a,b]$. (Figuring out what happens at the endpoints is the gist of the OP's question.)

Comment: I've updated the question to provide more context. I tried to present the question in the most simple form possible, but I may have omitted some important information while doing so.